# Selected options cleared when searching and adding more items in Angular mat-select with multiselect

Tags: angular, material-ui, drop-down-menu, angular-material

I have a mat-select in my Angular application with multiselect enabled. Inside the mat-select, there is an input that acts as a search for filtering the available options. The issue I am facing is that when I select some options, and then use the search input to filter and add more options to the selection, the previously selected options get cleared. I want the previously selected options to remain selected while I add more options using the search input. How can I achieve this behavior in my code?

```html
<mat-select formControlName="services" 
                    #searchSelect 
                    multiple
                    [(ngModel)]="selectedServiceIds">
            <mat-option class="searchable input-group" disabled>
              <input
                [disabled]="false"
                type="text"
                [(ngModel)]="searchService"
                [ngModelOptions]="{ standalone: true }"
                placeholder="Rechercher ..."/>

              <mat-icon class="float-right">search</mat-icon>
            </mat-option>
            <mat-option *ngFor="let service of services | filter : searchService"
                   [value]="service.id">
                        {{ service.name }}
            </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this kind of situation I would personally add a trackBy function into the ngFor. More info [here](https://angular.io/api/core/TrackByFunction)

Using a "standard" *ngFor, will implicitly recognize each entry of the given iterable under the hood trough the [object identity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/is).

In order to fix this issue, you will have to write something like this:

```html
<mat-option *ngFor="let service of services | filter : searchService; trackBy: trackByFn"
                   [value]="service.id">
                        {{ service.name }}
            </mat-option>
```

In your .ts

```js
trackByFn(_i: number, option: { id: unknown } ) {
  return option.id;
}
```

Comment: Nothing changed still got the same issue!!

Comment: Could you add more info regarding how you handle the selection? Thank you!